# R subset in association rules from spmf

Tags: r, subset, apriori

code:

```
data=read.csv("./spmf1234.csv",header=F);

df<- data.frame(do.call('rbind', strsplit(as.character(data$V1),'#',fixed=F)));

df2<- data.frame(do.call('rbind', strsplit(as.character(df$X1),'==>',fixed=F)));

df3=cbind(df2,df);

colnames(df3)=c("lhs","rhs","rule","support","confidence","lift");

df4 <- subset(df3, select = c(lhs,rhs,support,confidence,lift));

final=subset(df4,lhs!=1);
```

I am trying the above code on the csv file that I have obtained from spmf using fp-growth to get the association rules. I want all the rules having '1' in lhs to be removed, however this is not working.

csv file:

2 ==> 1 #SUP: 1 #CONF: 0.33333 #LIFT: 0.66667

1 ==> 2 #SUP: 1 #CONF: 0.33333 #LIFT: 0.66667

3 ==> 1 #SUP: 2 #CONF: 0.5 #LIFT: 1

1 ==> 3 #SUP: 2 #CONF: 0.66667 #LIFT: 1

3 ==> 2 #SUP: 2 #CONF: 0.5 #LIFT: 1

2 ==> 3 #SUP: 2 #CONF: 0.66667 #LIFT: 1

2 3 ==> 1 #SUP: 1 #CONF: 0.5 #LIFT: 1

1 3 ==> 2 #SUP: 1 #CONF: 0.5 #LIFT: 1

1 2 ==> 3 #SUP: 1 #CONF: 1 #LIFT: 1.5

3 ==> 1 2 #SUP: 1 #CONF: 0.25 #LIFT: 1.5

2 ==> 1 3 #SUP: 1 #CONF: 0.33333 #LIFT: 1

1 ==> 2 3 #SUP: 1 #CONF: 0.33333 #LIFT: 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
final=subset(df4,lhs!=1)
```

compares character to numeric, which does not work:

```
# > as.character(df4$lhs)
# [1] "2 "   "1 "   "3 "   "1 "   "3 "   "2 "   "2 3 " "1 3 " "1 2 " "3 "   "2 "   "1 "
```

you might wanna use a regular expression like this insead:

```
final = subset(df4, !grepl("1\\b", lhs))
# > final
#    lhs   rhs support     confidence          lift
# 1    2     1  SUP: 1  CONF: 0.33333  LIFT: 0.66667
# 3    3     1  SUP: 2      CONF: 0.5        LIFT: 1
# 5    3     2  SUP: 2      CONF: 0.5        LIFT: 1
# 6    2     3  SUP: 2  CONF: 0.66667        LIFT: 1
# 7  2 3     1  SUP: 1      CONF: 0.5        LIFT: 1
# 10   3   1 2  SUP: 1     CONF: 0.25      LIFT: 1.5
# 11   2   1 3  SUP: 1  CONF: 0.33333        LIFT: 1
```

**Add:**

```
## data preperation
data <- readLines(con = textConnection("  
2 ==> 1 #SUP: 1 #CONF: 0.33333 #LIFT: 0.66667
1 ==> 2 #SUP: 1 #CONF: 0.33333 #LIFT: 0.66667
3 ==> 1 #SUP: 2 #CONF: 0.5 #LIFT: 1
1 ==> 3 #SUP: 2 #CONF: 0.66667 #LIFT: 1
3 ==> 2 #SUP: 2 #CONF: 0.5 #LIFT: 1
2 ==> 3 #SUP: 2 #CONF: 0.66667 #LIFT: 1
2 3 ==> 1 #SUP: 1 #CONF: 0.5 #LIFT: 1
1 3 ==> 2 #SUP: 1 #CONF: 0.5 #LIFT: 1
1 2 ==> 3 #SUP: 1 #CONF: 1 #LIFT: 1.5
3 ==> 1 2 #SUP: 1 #CONF: 0.25 #LIFT: 1.5
2 ==> 1 3 #SUP: 1 #CONF: 0.33333 #LIFT: 1
1 ==> 2 3 #SUP: 1 #CONF: 0.33333 #LIFT: 1"))
r <- regexec(pattern = "([0-9 ]+)\\s==>\\s([0-9 ]+)\\s\\#SUP:\\s([0-9.]+)\\s\\#CONF:\\s([0-9.]+)\\s\\#LIFT:\\s([0-9.]+)", 
             text = data)
m <- regmatches(data, r)
df <- setNames(as.data.frame(do.call(rbind, lapply(m, "[", -1)), stringsAsFactors = FALSE), 
               c("lhs", "rhs", "support", "confidence", "lift"))

## rows to include/exclude
include <- sapply(strsplit(df$lhs, " "), function(x) !any(as.integer(x) %in% 1:1000))
df[include, ]
```

Comment: thanks, that really helps. just one question, if i use this method and do not want to include a list of numbers in lhs (or rhs), then i have to use this in a loop passing one number at a time. is there any other way more efficient to pass the complete list of numbers which i do not want to include in lhs (or rhs)

Comment: You can seperate the list of numbers with the pipe (or operator). E.g. `!grepl("\\b1\\b|\\b2\\b", lhs)` will exclude `1` and `2`. `\\b` is a word boundary marker: http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html.

Comment: i'm trying to use the following in a loop. kindly help:for(i in 0:1000)
{
  df2 = subset(df1, !grepl("\\bi\\b", lhs))
  df1=df2
}

Comment: What do you want to accomplish in the end? The `for` loop doesn't make sense in many ways to me, beginning with `paste0("\\b", i, "\\b")`instead of `"\\b1\\b|\\b2\\b"`.

Comment: i want to remove all those rows from the data set which has either 1,2,3 ... up till 1000 present in them.

Comment: See my add - this removes all rows which got 1 to 1000 on lhs